# Gradle fails to download artifacts from Nexus maven repository - 401 Authorization required

Tags: maven, gradle

I've configured gradle build to use our company's nexus repo but maven does not seem to be able to authorized correctly - I keep getting erros such as

```
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required:    https://maven.gooddata.com/nexus/content/repositories/gooddata/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.0.4/groovy-all-2.0.4.pom]
```

Strangely enough, the deploying to the same nexus repo (via mavenDeployer) is working seamlessly.

Below is part of my build script related to the maven repo configuration (maven_user and maven_password are defined in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties).

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

ext {
    repos = [
            my : "<my_repo_url>",
            my_snapshot : "<my_snapshots_repo_url>"
    ]

}


repositories {
    mavenLocal()

    maven {
        url repos.my
        credentials {
            username = maven_user
            password = maven_password
        }
    }
    maven {
        url repos.my_snapshot
        credentials {
            userName = maven_user
            password = maven_password
        }
    }

    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repository.codehaus.org/" }
    maven { url "http://sardine.googlecode.com/svn/maven" }
    maven { url "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org" }

}


uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository(url : repos.my) {
            authentication(userName : maven_user, password : maven_password)
        }
        snapshotRepository(url : repos.my_snapshot) {
            authentication(userName : maven_user, password : maven_password)
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions what's going on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your username property is capitalized wrongly and you should leave out the '=' sign with the username and password setting. Changing your repository definition to the following should solve your problems:

```
maven {
    url repos.my
    credentials {
        username maven_user
        password maven_password
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I wonder if there is a better way to catch errors like this?   Like a pass through a gradle build file to catch misspelled or unknown properties using a stemmer.

Answer (score 1):

Thread is a bit old now, but just wanted to highlight a gotcha I had when following the above .. my admin had created a password with both a single and double quote in, which resulted in a similar 401